# How to connect to Twitter and Facebook

Tags: facebook, post, twitter

Hey guys I'm creating a website and I'm wondering if there is a way, when the user writes a post, to share the post's link on his twitter and facebook accounts. How can I do that? I want the user to post certain text like: I just posted something on domain: www.domain.com/location

Comment: you must be living in caves to ask this question my friend ;-) havent you seen 1000s of sites already doing this ;-)

Comment: @Raj-despite all the smileys, unnecessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very possible. There are loads of tutorials on the API documentation pages for the two social networks:

- http://apiwiki.twitter.com/w/page/22554648/FrontPage
- http://developers.facebook.com/